# VBA to Import Worksheets Based on File Names in List

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to import a worksheet into my workbook.

```
Sub Importsheet()

Sheets.Add Type:= _
"E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & Range("E2").Text & ".csv"
ActiveSheet.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

EndSub
```

Basically, the folder path and file extension are constant, but the actual file name is drawn from cell E2.

I now have a list of file names I want to import. The list always starts in the same cell (A6), but the last row varies based on the list length.
I'm not sure how to change the code above so that the vba loops through all the names listed.

On top of that, I don't want any errors if the file doesn't exist, but rather, the text "Unable to Locate File" should populate in column B of the corresponding row (e.g. if the file listed in A6 doesn't exist, the value of cell B6 should now be "Unable to Locate File")

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Try `mycell.value` & also change your `Activesheets` to `Activesheet`. But I highly recommend to not use Select & Activate & Activesheet.  Change Also `Next Cell` to `Next mycell`

Comment: If `LastRowColumnA=1000` then `Set MyRange = Range("A6" & LastRowColumnA)` is `Range("A61000")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

- Use of `Activate`
- Use of `Activesheets`
- Use of `Next Cell` instead of `Next mycell` or `Next`
- Wrong Allocation of Range

**This Should Work:**

```
Sub ImportAllSheets()

Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRowColumnA As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

LastRowColumnA = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row



For Each myCell In .Range("A6:A" & LastRowColumnA)

    If Len(Dir("E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & myCell.Value & ".csv")) > 0 Then

        Sheets.Add Type:="E:\MyFolder\Manipulated Data\Test\" & myCell.Value & ".csv", After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

    Else: myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "File Not Found"
    End If

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great start! Now I have I need to deal with errors if the file doesn't exist. I'd like to insert "Unable to Locate File" in the adjacent cell if it doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: yes you can check if a file exists or not using `Dir` function. Added in the Code.